# Getting a 500 Error when inserting a new stream

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

Since about 5 hours ago we are getting the following error when creating a new stream either via the API or the 'try it' page:

Uncategorised|2020-10-06 11:09:00.4168|ERROR|The service youtube has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Internal error encountered. [500]
Errors [
Message[Internal error encountered.] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError] Domain[global]
]

sample json
{
"cdn": {
"format":"720p",
"frameRate":"30fps",
"ingestionInfo": null,
"ingestionType":"rtmp",
"resolution":"720p",
"ETag": null
},
"contentDetails": {
"closedCaptionsIngestionUrl": null,
"isReusable": false,
"ETag": null
},
"etag": null,
"id": null,
"kind": null,
"snippet": {
"channelId": null,
"description": null,
"isDefaultStream": null,
"publishedAt": null,
"title":"Stream_223",
"ETag": null
},
"status": null
}

Comment: worked it out....the 'format' prop is no longer supported.